# Uncheck Checkbox inside bulletdecorator WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

Looking for a little insight.

I have a checkbox that I have set to a style because I needed to make the actual box match with the text size and position. The style code is as follows:

```
Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="recogCheckbox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Margin="130,4,0,0"/>
                    <BulletDecorator Name="customBullet" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Recognition Call"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The xaml code for the checkbox is this:

```
<CheckBox FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="717,193,0,0" 
              Name="recognitionCheckBox" Style="{StaticResource recogCheckbox}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384" >
</CheckBox>
```

I am trying to use a clear button on my application so that it unchecks the  checkbox but when I reference the checkbox name 'recognitionCheckBox' by using `recognitionCheckBox.isChecked = false` it does not uncheck the checkbox which I think is because the actual box is inside the style which I am having trouble referencing in the C# code behind.

Does anyone know of a way to uncheck the checkbox within the style. I have been searching several sites but not found anything that has helped me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the IsChecked property of the inner CheckBox in the ControlTemplate to the IsChecked property of the CheckBox control itself using a {TemplateBinding}:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="recogCheckbox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="130,4,0,0"/>
                    <BulletDecorator Name="customBullet" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Width="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Recognition Call"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then it will reflect the current value of the IsChecked property of the Checkbox control.

Comment: I have tried putting in binding as you suggested. Even tried manual binding instead of template binding but still couldn't get the checkbox to clear. I maybe should explain more. Should someone on the form I am creating tick the checkbox then decide to press the clear form button it should clear the tick from the checkbox but it does not work.

Comment: Change the Mode of the Binding to TwoWay and it should work. I edited my answer.

Comment: Just got back to work today and tried it out and it works perfectly. Will need to remember this for future use. Thank you very much. Marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(v=vs.85).aspx add the following inside your control template after Stackpanel

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />

        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: I did see this article and ended up removing this from my code as it was only influencing the visibility of a particular element. I am trying to use the C# code behind to reference the checkbox element inside the style and set the isChecked element to false.